# Is their is a way to update property value at one place

Tags: polymer-1.0

In my application I have created paper element using dom-repeat to create below div. I have used data binding approach to bind property value to one place.same as below eq.

```
<div class="card-content" on-click="changed">Number of votes <span class="votes">[[count]]</span>
```

on-click event I want to change value of **count** property only at specific div, but as per data binding rules it's getting updated all places.

Please let me know if their is any way by which I can update value at single place without modifying other place.

Comment: I think you have to use some of the [dom-repeat API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat) (`modelForElement()`) but please make a more complete example first.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz this is first question I have posted in stackoverflow,going ahead I will paste complete code.